# JavaScript onClick work only after second click

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I found another similar questios, but almost all is for advanced things, like Android development. My question is simple, I think. I have this two codes:

```
function toggle(d)
{
    var o=document.getElementById(d);
    o.style.display=(o.style.display=='none')?'block':'none';
}
```

And in another file, I got that:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onmouseover="toggle('maisinfo');">More Info </a>
```

When I click on got the  mouseover (second code), it just work after second try.

Anyone know where is the problem?

Obs.: The first code is in the header.php and the second on single.php (WORDPRESS)

Comment: can you also post the html fragment with maisinfo id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first time, `d` is set by CSS; JavaScript doesn't see that style property (See [Get the Rendered Style](http://robertnyman.com/2006/04/24/get-the-rendered-style-of-an-element/)).  It initially sees `o.style.display === ""` (which is not 'none').  Consequently, the first click sets it to none and the second sets it to block.

Change it to:

```
o.style.display = (o.style.display === 'block') ? 'none':'block';
```

Answer (score 1):

because the first time the display property is not set therefore it is not  equal to "none"

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's nothing wrong with your code above. Maybe something's up with your style declaration, like setting it to block in the start which you might not want. Here's a simple JSFiddle I made for testing your code: http://jsfiddle.net/77DMd/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, you should maybe check your console for any warnings or errors. Whether the toggle function is actually declared before its being used etc.